# Help with piecewise function?

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, piecewise-continuity

I was hoping someone could help me in finding a solution to a question regarding piecewise functions?  I'm struggling because everything I have read / learned only has a single pronumeral and I can't find anything that contains multiple.  The question is:

"Determine the values for the pronumerals that make the following piece-wise functions continuous."

$y = 
\begin{cases} 
    2x-1,\quad x\le4 \\ 
    a+5x,\quad x>4
\end{cases}$

and

$y = 
\begin{cases} 
    -x,\quad\quad x\le a \\ 
    2+x,\quad\ a<x\le b \\
    2x-5,\quad x>b
\end{cases}$

Thanks in advance

Comment: I wonder which textbook you're reading from, because it's quite uncommon that a question like this is mentioned in an exercise without it having been covered in an example in the book before. In any case, I wonder if [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cJ5vSs7wvzc) can be of assistance to you. There's also [this one](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sx_9tjlucrU) and [this one](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=T8kfFcQci1U) which is extremely similar to your first example(so check out the last one first, then maybe see the others?).

Comment: What is a *pronumeral*?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well it's nothing complicated. All you have to do is to remember that for a piecewise function to be continuous everywhere
$$\lim_{x \to a^-}f(x) = \lim_{x \to a^+}f(x)$$
where $a$ is the point where the function changes/transforms into a different one.

Applying that logic in the first function,
$$\lim_{x \to 4^-}f(x) = \lim_{x \to 4^+}f(x)$$
$$\implies \lim_{x \to 4^-}2x-1=\lim_{x \to 4^+} 5x+a$$
$$\implies 4 \times 2 - 1 = 5\times 4 +a$$
$$\implies a=-13$$

Hence for the first function $a=-13$.

Similarly for the second one try to find the points where the function changes into a different one and equate the limits to find the value of the pronumeral *(Hint: The function changes twice in this case)*. Sometimes the piecewise function will also be told to be differentiable everywhere. In that case you may even need to find $f'(x)$ and equate it at the points where the derivative of the function changes.

Comment: Thank you so much for the explanation, it's greatly appreciated.  The videos also helped, thank you.  Are you able to expand further on the second one?  I know the 2 values I want to have connected are a and b but but how do I find their value?  All the examples / videos I have studied have numbers on the right of the functions and not pronumerals?

Comment: It's somewhat the same thing, in the first case the domain of the two parts of the piecewise function was fixed and we had to find the constant a to make them continuous. In the second one the functions are fixed but the domains are variable, so we need to find a and b so that entire function becomes. Essentially you are just finding the point of intersection of the three functions.

Comment: The two equations you must obtain are, (-a)=2+a and 2+b=2b-5

Comment: Thanks for the equations, so I am not actually trying to find the values for a and b? Just the equation?

Comment: Yeah, I mean finding the equations are necessary to find the value of a and b after all.